# Problem with system() call

Tags: android, system

I am using a system() call in a program , that is in c library. For 1st 9 calls it returns '0'(zero) after 10th call it returns 256. I do not know what does it mean. Please anybody help me. Following is the line of code

```
int returnValue= system("/system/bin/cat /dev/graphics/fb0 > /tmpdata/Screenshot/screenshot.bin");
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this man page](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html) dealing with the general unix `cat` command, an error code >0 simply means an error occurred.

> ```
> The following exit values shall be returned:
>
>  0
>     All input files were output successfully.
> >0
>     An error occurred.
> ```

Your `system()` call is attempting to concatentate two files, so perhaps there is a space issue or maybe the source file does not exist.

You may also wish to take a look at some recent [source code for Android cat](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/system/core.git;a=blob_plain;f=toolbox/cat.c;hb=HEAD) (cat.c) which gives some indicatations of the kind of things that trigger errors within cat.

Comment: number of calls to system is limited? because i'll be broken at 10th call each time.

Comment: @Kantesh No - you can call system() as often as you like, the **effect of calling it** (the creation of new data) is causing the limitation

Comment: I solved it restarting activity each time i'm done with the system call. I think there is a session or something like that and when restart the activity the process is restarted and reset.

Comment: @Kantesh I'd be a little concerned about restarting an Activity just to clear up a system() call. If you have time, you should investigate further otherwise you'll be coding by coincidence. However, if you're happy with the workaround then best of luck with your project.